# Want to put App Star Rating code cause Horizontal Issue

Tags: html, css, rating

I am trying to implement this code to put a star rating in front of app

```css
.checked {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<h2>Star Rating</h2>
<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
```

After implementation everything is working but STARS Showing Vertically. How to align Horizontally.

I tried many solution but didn't work for me .

like text-align:center; align:center;
margin 0, auto;

etc

Comment: The code you posted shows the stars lined up horizontally

Answer (score 0):

These stars should be centered by default, because `span` is inline tag, but maybe you have changed its behavior by some other CSS rules.

You can wrap HTML responsible for stars in some `div`:

```
<div class="center">
  <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
</div>
```

and center stars with `flexbox` rules:

```
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-itmes: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the flex approach. Although there is another alternative.
You can make the stars inline-block so that they take place next to each other.

```
.fa.fa-star {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: let me try it is working or not for me